# Fetching attachment from given .eml file and using that attachment to other mail

Tags: c#

I am working on code in C#,but not going through on thing that is I have saved some .eml file on my disk now I am parsing each eml file and creating a new mail adding the eml file data to the new mail but I am unable to attach the attachments present in the .eml file to the new mail , can anybody please help?

Comment: i am extracting the content from eml file in the following amnner

Answer (score 1):

I am using the follwing code but it shows the error ex = {"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.\r\n":null}

```
                foreach (CDO.IBodyPart attach in msg.Attachments)
                {

                    i++;
                    string filenm = "C:\\mail_automation\\attachments\\xyz" + i +".eml";
                    if (File.Exists(filenm))
                    {


                        string fn = attach.FileName;
                        attach.SaveToFile("C:\\mail_automation\\attachments\\xyz" + i + ".eml");
                        Attachment data = new Attachment(filenm);
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(data);                    


                    }
                    else
                    {

                        File.Create(filenm);
                        string fn = attach.FileName;
                        attach.SaveToFile("C:\\mail_automation\\attachments\\xyz" + i + ".eml");
                        Attachment data = new Attachment(filenm);
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(data);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the attachments and save them to disk first, then fetch it again into the new mail.

Code example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11380/A-C-Implementation-of-Mime-De-encode)

Comment: i am using the follwing code but it shows the error ex = {"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.\r\n":null}

Comment: Here in this code attach.FileName is returning empty. I want to get file name with extention, or only file extention will also work

Answer (score 0):

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); //store the mail into this ms 'memory stream'
ms.Position = 0;
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, attachmentName));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!